# Deciphering Sprockets - How require directive work? Seems like Magic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have been battling to understand Sprockets for Rails.

I will provide an example and maybe with this someone can tell me how SPROCKETS work. I have read http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sprockets/3.4.0/Sprockets/ and other info on the internet.

A default rails project comes in with

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
```

This produces the following html:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

How does Sprockets know where to get the jquery file? There is nothing else in the javascripts directory under assets.

I am trying to retrofit a static website that has tons of JS and less files and I having tons of troubles with the way assets are managed.

Comment: Your `Gemfile` includes the `jquery-rails` gem, the jquery.js lives here. Sprockets knows how to extract the assets from gems (which register the assets they provide with sprockets.)

Comment: @dsokurenko thanks for the quick reply. I guessed that. I was hoping to figure out how to tell my app or my manifest where my other files are, the same way it knows where jquery is.

Comment: You can directly reference the files located under `Rails.application.config.assets.paths ` dirs. Or you can add a new directory to search assets in using `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("any/other/dir")`

Comment: ok. I have all the javascripts inside the assets directory within other directories, but the require directive don't find them.